# Installing CTAN Packages on Fedora

Tags: ctan, linuxfedora

I recently installed TexLive on Fedora 35 using the package manager. In many cases if there is a specific package or class or style file I want installed I can do so through `dnf`. However, there are a few not available directly through  Fedora, like [JHEP.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/jhep) What is 'best practice' for installing such styles, given that the OS dissuades me from using `tlmgr`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: If yuo installed texlive via your Linux dist, it us unlikely that you will be able to use `tlmgr` to install packages (note that a package needs to be installable for texlive in the first place, not all packages on CTAN are). As you can see from the link only miktex is listed as having `jhep`. You you have to install by hand.

Comment: BTW: do you really want to use something that has not been updated since 2004?

Comment: Maybe an answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) could be useful to install an up to date texlive distribution in which you can use `tlmgr`